# Cannot convert date type yyyy-MM-dd to LocalDateTime in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-time

I am getting a date input from the user which is of type yyyy-MM-dd (e.g: 2023-02-26). I am trying to convert it to LocalDateTime format so that I will get something like this format, 2023-02-26 22:03:05.034981

I have tried examples available online like below.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime createdDate =  LocalDateTime.parse(projectSearchCriteria.getCreatedDate(), formatter);
```

But getting below error

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-02-26' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Any ideas on how to get this issue fixed.

**====================== Additional Info ===================**

I have converted so that the string input is now parsed to a LocalDate

[image]

But still it gives the below error

[image]

This is because I have the LocalDateTime format in the database

[image]

Is there any specific way how I can use the 2023-02-26 to find something like 2023-02-26 22:03:05.034981 in the database?

Comment: Where do you see the localdate**time** in 2023-02-26? That's a date.

Comment: In my case the user will provide 2023-02-26 as a string input. I have to convert it to something like this 2023-02-26 22:03:05.034981 as my database column has the timestamp without timezone.

Comment: So where are you getting the time from? You're just going to hardcode 3 minutes past 10? Or a random number generator?

Comment: Well your *pattern* expects a time as well: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`. Do you understand what that code does? What the meaning of the string is there? I would encourage you to parse the value as a `LocalDate` if that's what the user is actually entering - add the time part separately *after* parsing.

Comment: Oh oki. I thought may be it will add some default values like 00.00.00 to HH.mm.ss

Comment: You can instruct it to. It does not by itself.

Comment: @Michael could you have a look at the additional Info section and give me some insight if possible

Comment: @JonSkeet l could you have a look at the additional Info section and give me some insight if possible

Comment: Like `LocalDate.parse("2023-02-26").atTime(LocalTime.of(22, 3, 5, 34_981_000))`? Yields a `LocalDateTIme` of `2023-02-26T22:03:05.034981`. Or `LocalDate.parse("2023-02-26").atStartOfDay()` -> `2023-02-26T00:00`.

Comment: Use one of the `atTime` methods to get a `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2023-02-26" ) , 
    LocalTime.parse( "22:03:05.034981" ) 
)
```

## Details

> LocalDateTime format so that I will get something like this format, 2023-02-26 22:03:05.034981

You are confusing date-time objects with formatted text. A date-time object is *not* text, and **has no format**.

A date-time class can be used to *parse* a piece of text, extract meaning, and instantiate a date-time object. But the original text is discarded. Date-time objects and `String` objects are entirely separate and distinct.

> I am getting a date input from the user which is of type yyyy-MM-dd (e.g: 2023-02-26)

So parse that input text as a `LocalDate`, a date-only value without a time-of-day and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2023-02-26" ) ;
```

Apparently you want to attach to that date a particular time-of-day (for reasons you do not describe clearly). First parse your text input for that time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "22:03:05.034981" ) ;
```

Combine the two into a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

> Is there any specific way how I can use the 2023-02-26 to find something like 2023-02-26 22:03:05.034981 in the database?

Do you mean search the database for that exact date and time?

First, be sure the database table column is of a data type akin to the SQL data type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Verify the *WITHOUT* part, rather than *WITH*.

Then write your SQL query with the `?` syntax for passing a value via a prepared statement.

```java
String sql =
    """
    SELECT * 
    FROM some_table_
    WHERE date_time_ = ?
    ;
    """
;
```

Query.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieve found rows.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

By the way… Be aware that a `LocalDateTime` object is ambiguous and indefinite. Without the context of a zone or offset, a `LocalDateTime` object cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline.